# Why does the annual temperature range get bigger where latitude is higher?

Tags: meteorology

Why does the annual temperature range get bigger where latitude is higher?
Is it because of the ocean currents?
Or is there any other factor that causes this situation?

Comment: Without ocean currents, the difference would be even larger (as can be seen in interior Siberia, too far from the ocean for ocean currents to influence the temperature much).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the Earth Science Stack Exchange!

The bigger temperature range is because of the wide difference in the length of daylight seen in the higher latitudes. Depending on how high you are talking about, there can times where there is no sun for a month and vice versa with constant sun. Because of this there will therefore be more time for warmth and cooling as the Sun (or lack thereof) is what drives the diurnal temperature change the most.

Comment: Definitely the answer.  user21325 if your comparison interests lie specifically in like the tropics vs subtropics (where solar differences are a bit less wild) (places like the continental US and central\southern Europe), it's also lies in the proximity to colder airmasses (which aren't stationary, but propagate).  But in the larger picture, it's absolutely fluctuations in sunlight.

Comment: I can't type... "IT also lies in the proximity to colder airmasses", no "it's"

Comment: Thank you so much... I never thought of that!